# Get the file path from Send to option WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listener, desktop, sendto

I want to implement a wpf application that will listen
to an event that comes from the desktop from the `Send To` shortcut. Such as 
right click on the file and select `send to app`, then get the file path.

How would that be developed?

Comment: Sounds cool. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Win32.
I tried it a few month ago and it was great, but I lost the code and I can't find now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendTo resolves the link in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder and passes the filename as a parameter to the proper executable.  You need to make your program accept command parameters and then process them.

EDIT: I originally missed the mention of WPF.  So you could process command line args like this.

In you App.xaml add an entry for Startup like this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="App_OnStartup"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources />
</Application>
```

In your App.xaml.cs add the App_OnStartup like this and store the args into an accessible variable:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {

      public static string[] mArgs;

      private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Args.Length > 0)
          {
              mArgs = e.Args;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

In your main window get the args and do something with it:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      string[] args = App.mArgs;

      //do your procedure with the args!
    }
  }
}
```

Then place a shortcut to your program in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder.  When you right click on a file and SendTo your app, the filename will be the args that are passed into your app.

Comment: Where should I place the code? I'm working with WPF...

Comment: @Mr.Bean Override the `OnStartup` in your `App` class. The `StartupEventArgs` contains a collection of the command line parameters.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.
Do you know how to do it if the app already running?

Comment: @Mr. Bean.  It gets a little more tricky if you want it to be a single instance app that takes further command line arguments... here is a good article on how to accomplish that.  [http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx)